# .NET CLR Networking 4.0.0.0 -> create Performance Counter

Tags: c#-4.0, performancecounter

I try to create a performanceCounter in c# for monitoring Network connection of my browsers;

When I show the list for find my browser instanceName, this isn't monitored by the CounterPerformance ".NET CLR Networking 4.0.0.0"...

I create my counter :

```
bytesSent = new PerformanceCounter();
bytesSent.CategoryName = ".NET CLR Networking 4.0.0.0";
bytesSent.CounterName = "Bytes Sent";
bytesSent.InstanceName = instanceName; // instanceName of my browser.
bytesSent.ReadOnly = true;
```

And I display the list of instances monitored:

```
PerformanceCounterCategory category = new PerformanceCounterCategory(".NET CLR Networking 4.0.0.0");

string[] listMonitoredApplication = category.GetInstanceNames();
foreach (string monitoredInstanceName in listMonitoredApplication)
{
    Console.WriteLine(" - " + monitoredInstanceName);
}
```

I display list of performanceCounter every 1s, and in the list, there are just :

```
- myApplicationInstanceName
- _global_
```

Have you an idea, why my browser PerformanceCounter wasn't create?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because the browser doesn't use .NET framework classes to transfer data.  Browsers use native code.

You'll need to use a different performance counter, like those in the "Network Interface" category.  With the added wrinkle that the tcp/ip driver stack doesn't keep statistics for individual processes, only for a particular network interface.  No workaround for that.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the explanation!
Do you know, If I want to detect browsers network monitoring with an other solution? I search actually solution with Netsh trace, but if you have better solution, I'm interested!! :-)